# How do I style the SP2010 Welcome control?

Tags: 2010, css, branding

I've moved the Welcome control on my masterpage, and now the menu items do not render correctly. I've tried to find the appropriate CSS class name that is causing the problem, with no success.

What class names control the height of the menu items?

[image: Poorly-styled Welcome control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the classes you need to adjust (or probably re-override a style you overrode for your masterpage) you can use the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar (hit F12 on your keyboard).  Be sure to hit it after you open the window so the toolbar sees the menu opened.  Then use the selector to select the areas you need to work on.

Comment: Have you actually done this? Do you see the actual html making the menu? Or do you simply see the ie:menuitem tags?

Comment: Yes.  The trick is to make sure the menu is open before opening the Developer Toolbar.  For instance, when I do it I see classes like ms-MenuUIPopupInner, ms-MenuUILarge, ms-MenuUIUL, etc.  Reason I suggest this rather than listing all of the classes is that it is very dependent on  your situation as to which classes need to be adjusted.

Comment: Got it now. Had to close dev toolbar, then refresh the page, then open menu, then open toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

First you wanna find the class in corev4 css that controls the menu items

**Like this http://screencast.com/t/Wnz1BoVw**

I have added a background-color - now you wanna do your own thing.

When you have your changes in place - put them in another css file and place the after the corev4 (should not be a problem as corev4 is the first css to be loaded)

Best of luck

-chris